# Unable to Add/Update using 3-Tier Architecture

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, devexpress, n-tier-architecture

I have a table called `Currency` with two properties to be inserted which are `Unit` and `Rate`.

When I press `add` or `edit`, only `Unit` is saved but `Rate` remain `0`.

When I press `delete`, the record is deleted successfully.

Below is the code from **Data Layer**

```
public interface ICurrencyRepository
{
    List<Currency> GetAll();

    Currency GetById(int id);

    Currency Insert(Currency obj);

    void Update(Currency obj);

    void Delete(Currency obj);
}

public class CurrencyRepository : ICurrencyRepository
{
    public void Delete(Currency obj)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.Currencies.Attach(obj);
            db.Currencies.Remove(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<Currency> GetAll()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.Currencies.ToList();
        }
    }

    public Currency GetById(int id)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.Currencies.Find(id);
        }
    }

    public Currency Insert(Currency obj)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.Currencies.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public void Update(Currency obj)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.Currencies.Attach(obj);
            db.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code from **Business Layer**

```
public static class CurrencyServices
{
    static ICurrencyRepository repository;

    static CurrencyServices()
    {
        repository = new CurrencyRepository();
    }

    public static List<Currency> GetAll()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    public static Currency GetById(int id)
    {
        return repository.GetById(id);
    }

    public static Currency Insert(Currency obj)
    {
        return repository.Insert(obj);
    }

    public static void Update(Currency obj)
    {
        repository.Update(obj);
    }

    public static void Delete(Currency obj)
    {
        repository.Delete(obj);
    }
}
```

Below is the code from my **UI** (Page with grid)

```
    private void btnNew_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DocumentController.ActivateForm(typeof(Test), null);
        currencyBindingSource.DataSource = CurrencyServices.GetAll();
    }

    private void btnEdit_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currencyBindingSource.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            DocumentController.ActivateForm(typeof(Test), currencyBindingSource.Current as Currency);
            currencyBindingSource.DataSource = CurrencyServices.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Below is the code from my **UI** (Edit Page)

```
    bool isNew;
    public CurrencyEdit(Currency obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (obj == null)
        {
            currencyBindingSource.DataSource = new Currency();
            isNew = true;
        }

        else
        {
            currencyBindingSource.DataSource = obj;
            isNew = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isNew)
        {
            CurrencyServices.Insert(currencyBindingSource.Current as Currency);
        }

        else
        {
            CurrencyServices.Update(currencyBindingSource.Current as Currency);
        }
    }
```

Below is how I `currencyBindingSource` is getting created and bound in UI code.

1. Add bindingSource from toolbox.
2. Go to properties -> DataSource -> Add Project Data Source -> Object -> Choose `currency` table.
3. Add two textboxes -> Properties -> DataBindings -> EditValue -> Choose `Unit` and `Rate` from `currencyBindingSource`.

Comment: How would we know if we have absolutely no clue of how currencyBindingSource.Current is created or how your context is set up? By the way, why does the DataLayer return the instance it received from parameter and BusinessLayer does not return it?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto currencyBindingSource is added by adding bindingSource and set the datasource to currency. Isn't `current` one of bindingSource's properties? I'm not sure about your last question. I actually reference it from [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ncbr5axCabM].

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I checked the `currencyBindingSource.Current` at `btnSave` and realize that  `currencyBindingSource.Current` is only taking `Unit`.

Comment: So your problem got solved by your latest observation?

Comment: @RBT nop. I realized it's taking only `Unit`but I don;t know how to solve it.

Comment: Then essentially it is a problem with DevExpress tools which you are using at UI layer. There is no problem from business layer onward down to data access layer. The value of `Rate` is not being passed to the back-end layers at all so there is no point of them getting saved into DB. Would request you to share the details of how `currencyBindingSource` is getting created and bound in UI code?

Comment: @RBT added as per request.

Comment: I believe you are using DevExpress winForm controls. Correct?

Comment: @RBT yes. you are right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131609/discussion-between-rbt-and-active92).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. I believe you are missing some appropriate casts which are required:

```
private void btnSave_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    EfTestDataSet.CurrencyRow currencyRow = (EfTestDataSet.CurrencyRow)  ( currencyBindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row;

    if (isNew)
    {
        CurrencyServices.Insert(new Currency { Unit = currencyRow.Unit, Rate = currencyRow.Rate } );
    }
    else
    {
        CurrencyServices.Update(new Currency { Unit = currencyRow.Unit, Rate = currencyRow.Rate } );
    }
}
```

*Note*: `EfTestDataSet` is the name of the data source data set which got created while adding binding source in my application. It might be different in your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Instead of using Dataset, I replaced `currencyRow.Unit` with TextEdit since Dataset was not created when I added my binding source.

Comment: Super! Am glad that it helped. And thanks to you. Your post helped me learn about devExpress controls.